# annuity- find the present value of varying payments

Tags: actuarial-science

I am trying to find the present value of an annuity, where we have a $20$-year annuity immediate where the first payment is  $1000$, and each subsequent payment is increased by either $50$ for
the first $10$ payments or by $100$ for the last $10$ payments.

The 1st payment= $1000$ (at time 1)

Y2 TO Y10 payment = $1000 + 50$ = $1050$

Y11 TO Y20 payment = $1000 + 50 + 100$ = $1150$

I did the present value of each individual payment using the principle
$PV = Pν + (P + Q)ν^{2} + (P + 2Q)ν^{3} + ... + (P + (n − 1)Q)ν^{n}$

$PV = 1000v +1050v^{2} + 1100v^{3} + ... + 1450v^{10} + 1600v^{11} + 1750v^{12} + 1900v^{13} +...+ 4300v^{20}$

then

$$\require{enclose} PV = 1000 [ 50a_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i} + 150v^{10}  a_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i}]  \tag{1}$$

where $i = 10$%

I wasn't sure if I derived the formula correctly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe the cash flow does not match the equation of value you wrote.

You say that the payments are increased by $50$ for each year for the first ten years, and then by $100$ for each year for the last ten years.  But the way you wrote it, you're increasing the payments by $150$ in the last ten years.  Which is it?

My interpretation of the question would have the payments be:
$$1000, 1050, 1100, 1150, 1200, 1250, 1300, 1350, 1400, 1450, \\
1550, 1650, 1750, 1850, 1950, 2050, 2150, 2250, 2350, 2450.$$  Note that the total increase from the first payment to the last is $50(9) + 100(10) = 1450 = 2450 - 1000$.

In such a case, there are multiple ways to write the equation of value.  One way is to take the level payments of $1000$ out, and then what is left are two increasing annuities, one deferred by one year, and the other deferred by $10$ years.  Refer to the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\text{Year} & \text{Level Payment} & \text{Increasing 1} & \text{Increasing 2} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
1 & 1000 & 0 & 0 & 1000 \\
2 & 1000 & 50 & 0 & 1050 \\
3 & 1000 & 100 & 0 & 1100 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
10 & 1000 & 450 & 0 & 1450 \\
11 & 1000 & 500 & 50 & 1550 \\
12 & 1000 & 550 & 100 & 1650 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
20 & 1000 & 950 & 500 & 2450 \\
\end{array}$$
This gives us the equation of value
$$\require{enclose}
\begin{align}
PV
&= 1000(v + v^2 + \cdots + v^{20}) + (50v^2 + 100v^3 + \cdots + 950v^{20}) \\ &\qquad + (50v^{11} + 100v^{12} + \cdots + 500v^{20}) \\
&= 1000 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{20} i} + 50 v (Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{19}i} + 50 v^{10}(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i}.
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, we can structure the payments as follows:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\text{Year} & \text{Level Payment} & \text{Increasing 1} & \text{Increasing 2} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
1 & 950 & 50 & 0 & 1000 \\
2 & 950 & 100 & 0 & 1050 \\
3 & 950 & 150 & 0 & 1100 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
10 & 950 & 500 & 0 & 1450 \\
11 & 1450 & 0 & 100 & 1550 \\
12 & 1450 & 0 & 200 & 1650 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
20 & 1450 & 0 & 1000 & 2450 \\
\end{array}$$
This gives the equation of value
$$PV = 950 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i} + 1450 v^{10} a_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i} + 50 (Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i} + 100v^{10} (Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i}.$$
You might ask, why would we write it this way instead of the previous?  Well, notice that even though there is one more annuity symbol, there's actually only *two* different ones, rather than three in the first equation of value.  In other words, things factor more nicely in the second equation:
$$PV = 50\left( (19 + 29v^{10})a_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i} + (1 + 2v^{10})(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{10}i}\right).$$
In both cases, the answer is the same, approximately $11843.639297$.  But no matter how you write the equation of value, you must use an increasing annuity symbol $(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}i}$.

Comment: thank you for clarifying and find where my mistake was. For some reason I'm getting 11299.51.

Comment: I did $50[ (19+29(1/1.1)^{10}) ((1-(1.1)^{-10})/0.1) + (1+2(1/1.1)^{10}) (22.89134211)]$. For (Ia) I did $[(1-(1.1)^{-10})/0.1) - 10(1/1.1)^{10}]/0.1 = 22.89134211$

Comment: wait, I made a mistake I use a and not "a double dot" for the formula (Ia)

Comment: @comp890 Your formula for $\require{enclose}(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}i}$ is not correct.  you can check by manually calculating $v + 2v^2 + \cdots + 10v^{10}$ and seeing it does not equal $22.8913$.  The correct formula is $$(Ia)_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}i} = \frac{\ddot a_{\enclose{actuarial}{n}i} - nv^n}{i}.$$  I see you figured it out, nice job!